# Expand/collapse div inside full page.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, gallery, fullpage.js

I am making a website with fullpage.js

In one of the sections, I would like three images in full width, on top of each other.

(all images closed)  http://cphz4media.com/test/images/01.jpg

Every image are put in a div, and contains some information. So far so good.
The tricky part (for me at least), is that every image actually are fullscreen-images, and should expand when activated through a button!

– The first image expands downwards, the middle image expands up and down, and the last image expands upwards.

(image 1 expanding)  http://cphz4media.com/test/images/02.jpg

Do you know of any gallery/jquery-plugin, that would do the trick? :)

Comment: image 2 expanding: http://cphz4media.com/test/images/03.jpg

Comment: image 3 expanding: http://cphz4media.com/test/images/04.jpg

Comment: You probably want to code it yourself using jQuery and CSS.